# Javascript regex to split a string by &nbsp & html tag

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I have a string `Automation  Donot Delete - Automation 1&nbsp;<i class="arrow"></i>&nbsp;GoogleContacts - Automation` that is extracted through selenium innerHtml.

I want to split the above string separated by `&nbsp;<i class="arrow"></i>&nbsp;`.

I did tried to replace the nbsp with additional space and split the string but it is splitting the string into three parts rather two as there is an additional space between `Automation   Donot Delete"`

I did tried the below scripts but nothing resolved my issue.

```
var input="Automation Donot Delete - Automation 1&nbsp;<i clas =icon></i>&nbsp;GoogleContacts - Automation
input1=input.replace("<[^>]+>","")
input2=input1.replace("&nbsp;"," ")
var arr=input2.split("\s{2,}","")
```

I am expecting an array as `['Automation  Donot Delete - Automation 1' , 'GoogleContacts - Automation']` but it is giving me `['Automation', 'Donot Delete - Automation 1', 'GoogleContacts - Automation']`

Comment: You can try with unescapeHtml4
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2):

I do not understand why you are trying to replace parts before splitting?

You can simply split the string, as you describe by using `split`:

```js
let input = 'Automation  Donot Delete - Automation 1&nbsp;<i class="arrow"></i>&nbsp;GoogleContacts - Automation';

const inputSplit = input.split('&nbsp;<i class="arrow"></i>&nbsp;')

console.log(inputSplit);
```

If you want to be more fancy, and also going by your questions title, maybe you want to split on both `&nbsp;` and `<>`. Then you need some RegEx.

Doing simply `input.split(/(&nbsp;|<[^>]+>)/)` would give us an array of all parts, eg: `["Automation  Donot Delete - Automation 1", "&nbsp;", "", "<i class=\"arrow\">", "", "</i>", "", "&nbsp;", "GoogleContacts - Automation"]`

This is a bit annoying, so we could update our regex to do a non-capturing group; `input.split(/(?:&nbsp;|<[^>]+>)/)` and this would give us same array but any instance of `&nbsp;` and `<>` would be empty strings, eg. `["Automation  Donot Delete - Automation 1", "", "", "", "GoogleContacts - Automation"]`

To fix that we can filter away any empty strings with `input.filter((i) => i !== '')`.

All of this together:

```js
let input = 'Automation  Donot Delete - Automation 1&nbsp;<i class="arrow"></i>&nbsp;GoogleContacts - Automation';

const inputSplit = input.split(/(?:&nbsp;|<[^>]+>)/).filter((i) => i !== '');

console.log(inputSplit);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

https://jsfiddle.net/0xey2394

```
function splitString() {
  var input = document.getElementById("inputString").value;
  input=input.replace("&nbsp;"," ")
  var arr = input.split(/<i class="arrow"><\/i>/);
  document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = arr[0].trim();
  document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = arr[1].trim();
}
```